# Bootstrap button loading state and Ajax helpers in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Ajax form with a button, and I want the button to have the "loading" text while client is waiting for respond from the server... Here is what I have now:

```
<div id="updateButton">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Donate", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "updateButton" ,InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, }))
    {
        <input type='hidden' name='receiverID' value=@Model>
        <button type="submit" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary" >Loading state </button>
    }
</div>
```

but it does not work.

bootstrap.js , jquery.js and jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js are included...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Ajax.BeginForm` options to change the button loading state, see below:

```
<script>
    function onBegin() {
        $("#mybtn").hide();
    }

    function onComplete() {
        $("#mybtn").show();
    }
</script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Donate", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "updateButton", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, LoadingElementId = "resultLoadingDiv", OnBegin = "onBegin", OnComplete = "onComplete" }))
{
    <input type='hidden' name='receiverID' value=@Model>
    <input type="submit" id="mybtn" value="OK" />
    <button type="button" id="resultLoadingDiv" style="border: slategray 1px solid; display: none;margin: auto;">
           Loading...
    </button>
}
```

If you only want to use bootstrap, see below:

```
   <div id="updateButton">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Donate", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "updateButton" ,InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, }))
        {
            <input type='hidden' name='receiverID' value=@Model>
            <button type="submit" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary" >Loading state </button>
        }
    </div>
    <script>
        $('.btn').click(function () {
                var btn = $(this)
                btn.button('loading')
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        btn.button('reset')
                    }, 3000);
                });
     </script>
```

Comment: ahh, there is a problem... The "loading" text is added under the button, not instead of it...

Comment: @Anarion, If you want to keep your original code, just use the script i updated.

Comment: This works! But is there a way to use OnCopmlete to reset button state?

Comment: Ah, did it already... Sorry for all the silly questions - I am very new to web technologies.